# Cart session and displaying number of items in cart return undefined in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have `Cart()` button at the top of the page where it's stores and shows user cart number of products. It's visible also on non-logged in users and they can place products in cart. In Laravel 4.2 this works perfectly but I've migrated to Laravel 5.4 and no I facing this problem.

This is the function

```
protected function setupLayout()
{

    $user = self::getCurrentUser();       
    View::share('user', $user);

     // this is the part which cause error
    View::share('cartCount', count(Session::get('cart', array())));
}

public static function isLoggedIn()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user !== null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This I have in my view

```
@if(!Auth::check())

    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/cart') }}">Cart ( {{ $cartCount }} )</a></li>

@else 

    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/cart') }}">Cart ( {{ $cartCount }} )</a></li>

@endif
```

The error

> Undefined variable: cartCount

Any ideas why this works on ver 4.2 but not work on ver 5.4 Laravel?

`dd(Session::get('cart', array()))` return `Array ()` which is correct if there is no products in cart. When there are products it is showing in array.

I'm sure that there are products in cart because `dd(Session::get('cart', array()))` return

```
array:2 [▼
  2 => array:5 [▶]
  227 => array:5 [▶]
]
```

Comment: Where do you define `setupLayout` and `isLoggedIn` ?

Comment: `isLoggedIn` is in question. `setupLayout` is not in use. Should be deleted. Sorry, it's removed

Comment: setupLayout not in use? could that be the problem because that's where you're sharing the variable :)

Comment: Hm, good question. I have another counter in there which I've removed from question which is working `View::share('messagesCount', $user->messages()->where('read_state', '0')->where('from_admin', '1')->count());` just this one doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this :

```
@if(!Auth::check())

    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/cart') }}">Cart ( {{ isset($cartCount) ?  $cartCount : 0}} )</a></li>

@else 

    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/cart') }}">Cart ( {{ isset($cartCount) ?  $cartCount : 0}} )</a></li>

@endif
```

**Updated**:

```
protected function setupLayout()
{

    $user = self::getCurrentUser();  

    $data = array(
    'user' => $user,
    'cartCount' => count(Session::get('cart', array())),
    );     
    View::share('data', $data);


}

@if(!Auth::check())

    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/cart') }}">Cart ( {{ $data['cartCount']}} )</a></li>

@else 

    <li><a href="{{ URL::to('/cart') }}">Cart ( {{ $data['cartCount']}} )</a></li>

@endif
```

Hope this work for you!!!

Comment: Like the other answer. This only makes the page to load but if I put items in cart still showing `0`

Comment: I've updated the question with `dd(Session::get('cart', array()))`  response, so I'm sure that there are products in it.

Comment: If I use directly in blade `({{ count(Session::get('cart', array())) }})` it is showing correct number.

Comment: Still error `Undefined variable: data` Ive tried it also in `AppServiceProvider` in `boot()` function.

Comment: @Ivan : If you can use $cartCount directly in your blade file then i think you can try with 'return view()'

Comment: I've tried everything and not working. Ended up with `({{ count(Session::get('cart', array())) }})` but I think this is not a good solution, right?

Answer (score 0):

Please update it to {{ $cartCount or '0' }}. So in case if the variable is not set when user first loads the page at that time it will show 0 and you won't get any error.

Comment: This `{{ $cartCount ? '0' : $cartCount }}` retunr same error.

Comment: Please try what I said in my answer.

    {{ $cartCount or '0' }}

Comment: The page is loading. But doesn't show number of products when I add them in cart. Always show `0`